# How to change the head section of Index.html in a Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

In the head section of my Ruby on Rails app I am only able to see the following CSS and JS file when I view the source code in browser.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/stylesheets/default.css" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />

<script src="/javascripts/default.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload">
```

I have added bootstrap CSS and JS files to the `app/assets/stylesheets`and `app/assets/javascripts` and have changed the `application.css` and `application.js` files. Still I am not able to see those files in source code.

Comment: Can you paste code of  default.js , default.css and header of application.html.erb ?

Comment: @DivyangHirpara `/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the`

Comment: @divyangHirpara `* compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require default
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */`

Comment: @Vucko I don't know why it's using default.css and where to locate that file? I am not using bootstrap-sass gem because someone said it's easier this way to add files and require them in `application.css/js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">` to the `application.html.erb` file.

Thanks to @Deepak for giving me a lead to find an alternate solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to require those files using `require_tree .` or explicitly

   **application.css**

   ```
   /*
   *= require self
   *= require_tree .
   */
   ```

   **application.css**

   ```
   //= require self
   //= require_tree .
   ```
2. you can use `content_for` tag

   **application.html.haml**

   ```
   %head
     = yield :head
   ```

   **index.html.haml**

   ```
   = content_for :head do
     = javascript_include_tag "bootstrap"
   ```

Comment: I required those files and secondly I am using application.html.erb format. Do I have to use content_for in that file?

Comment: yes, if you want to add something to head from any other file then you can use it. And you can use it in .erb as well

Comment: just convert above haml to erb

Comment: Umm.. I added stylesheets folder in public directory and added bootstrap files in that. That way it worked. and moreover I was looking for `application.html.erb` file only. I thought it should be `index.html`. Thanks for that. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your application.css add the following to include your files

```
*= require bootstrap
*= require default
*= require_tree .
*/
```

Comment: Already added:

 *= require bootstrap
 *= require default
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */